# Visual Studio Code and Chrome Debug: Breakpoints won't be hit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am using browserify with grunt to develop an angular spa. My problem is, that the breaktpoints won't be hit, when i set sourceMaps to true. Browserify writes it's output into the dist-folder and the sourcemaps uri is attached at the end of the output file there. When i start debugging, chrome pops up and my app's login appears. When i've logged in, the breakpoints should hit, but they won't. I am assuming, that the extension (maybe) cannot find the sourcemaps the right way or something like that. Please help me, i like that extension a lot! See my filestructure, breakpoints and launch.config [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMTr4.png)

Kind regards!
Carsten

Comment: I believe Visual Studio Code only supports JavaScript debugging in Node.js apps right now

Comment: Yeah, the blank VSTC. But with the extension "Chrome Debug", it should debug client JS too.